# regular expression match issue in Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7, want to use regular expression to find the `Hello` part of a given string. The rule is, `Hello` maybe in the pattern starts with `{(1N)`, `{(2N)` (until `10N`), or combination of them `{(1N,2N,3N,4N)`, and ends with `}`.

Besides match the `Hello` part, I also want to know if `1N` match, or `2N` match or `10N` match, or either `1N` or `2N` match.

Any solutions are appreciated.

```
  Some content  {(1N,2N,3N,4N) Hello } Some content 

  Some content  {(1N) Python } Some content 

  Some content {(2N) Regex } Some content
```

In the first example, I want to know `1N`,`2N`,`3N`,`4N` matches, and the matched string is `Hello`;

In the 2nd example, I want to know `1N` matches, and matched string is `Python`;
In the 3rd example, I want to know `2N` matches, and matched string is `Regex`;

regards,
Lin

Comment: Can you show your own attempt ?

Comment: @pistache, I tried to match `{(1N (.*?) }` through `{(10N (.*?) }`, match 10 times for a given string, which sounds a bit stupid and I also need to remove some prefix unnecessary matches, so it is why I come here to ask. Do you have some more efficient solutions? :)

Comment: Have you tried playing around in any of the online Python regex testers?  Since you have so many variables you might have to make several passes - first write an expression to match the ```\{\(.*?\) Hello \}``` part.

Comment: Thanks @wwii, I may mis-interpreter the question. `Hello` part could be any string, I just use `Hello` as example, I will update the question. If you have any good ideas, it will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [82]: string = "Some content  {(1N,2N,3N,4N) Hello } Some content"
In [83]: result = re.findall(r"(\((?:(?:10|[1-9])N(?:,|\)))+)\s*(\w+)", string)
In [84]: nums = re.findall(r"10N|[1-9]N", result[0][0])
In [85]: nums
Out[85]: ['1N', '2N', '3N', '4N']
In [86]: matchString = result[0][1]
In [87]: matchString
Out[87]: 'Hello'
```

For the new string:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: string = "{(1N,2N,3N,4N) Hello } Some Content {(5N) World }"

In [3]: re.findall(r"(\((?:(?:10|[1-9])N(?:,|\)))+)\s*(\w+)", string)
Out[3]: [('(1N,2N,3N,4N)', 'Hello'), ('(5N)', 'World')]

In [4]: result = re.findall(r"(\((?:(?:10|[1-9])N(?:,|\)))+)\s*(\w+)", string)

In [5]: nums = [re.findall(r"10N|[1-9]N", item[0]) for item in result]

In [6]: nums
Out[6]: [['1N', '2N', '3N', '4N'], ['5N']]

In [7]: matchString = [s[1] for s in result]

In [8]: matchString
Out[8]: ['Hello', 'World']
```

Comment: Smart solution! Vote up! Thanks jcxu! Would you mind to explain a bit more when you use `?:` 3 times?

Comment: Hi jcxu, tried your solution and met with one new issue, for input string like this `{(1N,2N,3N,4N) Hello } Some Content {(5N) World }`, I want to get matched information as, `Hello` with `1N`, `2N`, `3N`, `4N`, and `World` with  `5N`, i.e. I want to match multiple times in a non-greedy way, after we find a match, we will always continue to match another one, is there a solution?

Comment: Your solution output of my input string above is only `Hello` with `1N`, `2N`, `3N`, `4N`.

Comment: Sorry to reply so late. I have updated the solution, for your first question, the `?:` means I don't need capture the content, because the first  parentheses contains all I need, the regex will be faster.

Comment: Thanks jcxu. Tried your solution works pretty good. Just to confirm my understanding is correct, your have 4 match groups, `(?:10|[1-9])` and 
`(?:,|\))` are non-capturing group and `(\((?: (?:10|[1-9]) N (?:,|\)))` and `(\w+)` are capturing group, correct understanding? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, find another bug in your regular expression, if input is `"Some content  {(1N,2N,3N,4N) Hello World } Some content"`, notice there is a space between `Hello` and `World`, you can only match until `Hello`. I think you should match until the next `}`, correct?

Comment: BTW, I fix it by using this `(\((?:(?:10|[1-9])N(?:,|\)))+)(.*?)\s?}`, not sure if you see any bugs in my above regex? Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks jcxu for the clarification, mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions cannot really count (which is why you say you tried to write 10 times the same pattern), but instead you can match the sequence and then split to count :

```
In [100]: match = re.compile(r"\{\s?\(\s?((\d+N,?)+)\)\s?(.*)\s?\}").search("Some content  { (1N,2N,3N,4N) Hello } Some content")

In [101]: items, _, text = match.groups()

In [102]: splitted = items.split(',')

In [103]: print(splitted)
['1N', '2N', '3N', '4N']

In [104]: print(text)
Hello
```

NOTE: All the `\s?` are there to handle optional blanks, remove them if you know you don't need at certain places.

Comment: Thanks pistache, I may mis-interpreter the question. `Hello` part could be any string, I just use `Hello` as example, I will update the question. If you have any good ideas, it will be great.

Comment: Cool, thanks pistache. What means `_` in your line `[101]`? Thanks.

Comment: `_` is the variable name I assign to the second capture group. The second capture group temporarily holds each item such as "1N" or "10N", and when it's read after matching it will only return the last match for this subpattern. As I don't actually need this value (but need the group to be in the pattern), I save it to a name that I'm sure ill never use. It would actually be better to make it a non-capturing group (change `(\d+N,?)` to `(?:\d+N,?)`, and then remove `_,` from the Python code, but I wasn't sure you knew about non-capturing groups.

Comment: Note that it looks /a little bit/ like your task would be better done using a lexer or a tokenizer than regular expressions. Doesn't change anything in the current example, but maybe you'll face at some point some unexpected shortcomings of regular expressions (due to irregular input) that would make a proper parser required.

Comment: Thanks pistache, vote up for your both replies, want to confirm for `\s?`, you mean match a space or tab in a non-greedy way? Confused why need `?` here.

Comment: Or you mean match zero or one space? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, your code seems has a bug? `(\d+N,?)`, there is an additional `,` which is not needed since `1N` is not written as `1N,`, correct?

Comment: `\s?` means zero or one whitespace (not greedy, as it is not a wildcard match anyway)/. I added these because the input format didn't seem coherent about whitespaces (there's one before `}`, but not after `{`). The `,?` is required to match zero-or-one `,` that will be there except for the last item as it used as separator.

Comment: Thanks pistache, vote up for your reply. I am a bit confused for your comments "`\s?` means zero or one whitespace (not greedy ...", I understand `\s` means space, and `?` means qualifier zero or one match previous stuff, and confused what do you mean non-greedy here? I think `\s?` will match zero or one spaces. If you could show an example, it will be great.

Comment: I just said "not greedy" to confirm the "in a non-greedy way" part in your post. "Greedy" does not apply in this context as it is not a wildcard match. `\s?` will indeed match zero or one whitespaces (space, tab, newline, etc)

Comment: Thanks pistache for the clarification, I just want to double confirm I understand your points correctly. If there is a space, `\s?` will try to match the space, other than not match (non-greedy way), correct?

Comment: Yes. You can skip it if you know you don't have a whitespace at that point.

Comment: Thanks pistache, I am not sure if there is a whitespace, but I think using \s? is always has no harm, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120935/discussion-between-pistache-and-lin-ma).